# SQL View slow to run

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, sql-server-2014

I have the following SQL statement but it takes 20 seconds to run, how can I make it faster ?

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT
    dbo.pod.order_no,
    dbo.pod.order_line_no,
    dbo.poh.currency,
    dbo.pod.warehouse,
    dbo.pod.product,
    dbo.poh.address1,
    dbo.pod.description,
    dbo.pod.date_required,
    dbo.pod.qty_ordered,
    dbo.pod.qty_received,
    dbo.pod.qty_invoiced,
    dbo.pod.status,
    dbo.poh.date_entered,
    dbo.stock.analysis_c,
    dbo.stock.catalogue_number,
    dbo.stock.drawing_number,
    dbo.poh.date_required AS OriginalRequiredDate,
    dbo.stock.standard_cost,
    dbo.poh.supplier_ref,
    dbo.stock.reorder_days,
    dbo.pod.local_expect_cost,
    dbo.poh.supplier,
    dbo.pod.qty_ordered - dbo.pod.qty_received AS qty_outstanding,
    dbo.stock.warehouse AS warehouse2
FROM dbo.stock
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.pod
    ON dbo.stock.product = dbo.pod.product
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.poh
    ON dbo.pod.order_no = dbo.poh.order_no
WHERE (dbo.pod.status <> 'C')
AND (dbo.poh.status <> '9')
AND (dbo.stock.analysis_c IN ('FB', 'FP', 'RM', '[PK]'))
AND (dbo.pod.qty_ordered - dbo.pod.qty_received > 0)
AND (dbo.stock.warehouse = 'FH')
```

The execution plan says remote Query taking up 89% - These tables are located through a linked server.

Comment: what does the execution plan tell you is taking the time?

Comment: Please post execution plan and indexes of your table. It will help.

Comment: @emma why you expect faster times? if is a query joining billion of rows using unindexed columns is really fast! you need to share more details about the context: data structure, number of rows, indexes... making **wild** guesses i would change `(dbo.pod.qty_ordered - dbo.pod.qty_received > 0)` into `(dbo.pod.qty_ordered > dbo.pod.qty_received)`

Comment: On top of that - having clauses in `WHERE` statement, make your `RIGHT`/`LEFT` joins become `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: The execution plan says remote Query taking up 89% - These tables are located through a linked server.

Comment: You need to include the query plan. The percentage doesn't tell anything. Is the query as slow if you run it directly on the linked server?

Comment: I've ran it a few times directly on the linked server and it takes anything from 4 - 13 seconds. That's using the modified version from Evaldas below.

Comment: Are all three of these 'tables' actually views to tables on a linked server?  *(And are they all on the same linked server?)* Or is some of the data on your server and some of the data on the linked server?

Comment: query execution plan directly on the linked server says 70% taken up with Table Scan (estimated row count 56,713) : OBJECT: (stock as [S], WHERE: ( S.warehouse=’FH’ AND S.analysis_c=’PK’ or s.analysis_c=’RM’ or s.analysis_c=’FP) or s.analysis_c = ‘FB’)

Comment: Yes all views to tables on a linked server - and yes - on the same linked server.

Comment: Can you tell us what indexes exist on those tables (on the linked server), and/or can you add the indexes recommended to you in the answers below?  *(You need to add them to the tables on the linked server, not to the views.)*

Comment: Not really familiar with indexes, how can I see ? I would have to check with someone before adding any indexes into the linked server.

Comment: @Emma - Have the whole discussion with that person then; You're running this query, it's slow, what indexes are there, can you add new ones, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd move the (dbo.stock.warehouse = 'FH') up the where clause to be the first item in the where clause since this is your main table. I'd then run the query through query profiler to see where the lag is, this might help narrow the area that needs to change

Comment: I also have doubts on why she needs `SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT` when there's no `ORDER BY`. She should get rid of `TOP` operator.

Comment: There's no guarantee on what order predicates within a `WHERE` clause will be evaluated in. If the optimizer has enough information, it should be evaluating the predicates in the optimal order. If the optimizer has deficient information, it may re-order the predicates such that they're not optimal. In neither case does the *textual* order in which the predicates appear have any effect.

Comment: it keeps putting the top in automatically Evaldas

Comment: @Emma - "it" being the SSMS View Designer? The best thing you can do is to learn to stop using the SSMS designers (they do some horrible things) and just write your SQL in query windows. Trust me, a query window *won't* add anything in "automatically".

Comment: if you run the query in a new query window from within management studio, right click in the windows and select 'display estimated execution plan'

Answer (score 0):

As in comments, there shouldn't be any TOP statement (what keeps putting it automatically?).

I'd rewrite your view like that (for readability):

```
SELECT P.order_no
    , P.order_line_no
    , T.currency
    , P.warehouse
    , P.product
    , T.address1
    , P.[Description]
    , P.date_required
    , P.qty_ordered
    , P.qty_received
    , P.qty_invoiced
    , P.[Status]
    , T.date_entered
    , S.analysis_c
    , S.catalogue_number
    , S.drawing_number
    , T.date_required AS OriginalRequiredDate
    , S.standard_cost
    , T.supplier_ref
    , S.reorder_days
    , P.local_expect_cost
    , T.supplier
    , P.qty_ordered - P.qty_received AS qty_outstanding
    , S.warehouse AS warehouse2
FROM dbo.stock AS S
RIGHT JOIN dbo.pod AS P
    ON S.product = P.product
LEFT JOIN dbo.poh AS T
    ON P.order_no = T.order_no
WHERE P.[Status] <> 'C'
    AND T.[Status] <> '9'
    AND S.analysis_c IN ('FB', 'FP', 'RM', '[PK]')
    AND P.qty_ordered - P.qty_received > 0
    AND S.warehouse = 'FH';
```

Also, I'd create following indexes, which should increase performance (hopefully I didn't miss any columns):

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_Stock_product_warehouse_analysisC_iColumns
    ON dbo.Stock (product, warehouse, analysis_c)
    INCLUDE (catalogue_number, drawing_number, standard_cost, reorder_days);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_Pod_product_orderNo_status_qtyOrdered_qtyReceived_iColumns
    ON dbo.Pod (product, order_no, [status], qty_ordered, qty_received)
    INCLUDE (order_line_no, warehouse, [Description], date_required, qty_invoiced, [status], local_expect_cost);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_Poh_orderNo_Status_iColumns
    ON dbo.Poh (order_no, [Status])
    INCLUDE (currency, address1, date_entered, date_required, supplier_ref, supplier);
```

Comment: Msg 1939, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot create index on view 'stock' because the view is not schema bound.

Comment: The answer to "what keeps putting it automatically?" is almost certainly the SSMS View Designer. It's a horrible tool that does things like this (and allowing you to "sort" a view), thus perpetuating poor practice.

Comment: To that error message. Apparently `dbo.stock` is not a table. Create indexes in underlying tables (if it's possible).

Answer (score 0):

Since there isn't really much to work on, just general guesses that what could help. You have 5 criteria in your SQL that could help to reduce the amount of rows:

```
pod.status <> 'C'
pod.qty_ordered - pod.qty_received > 0
poh.status <> '9'
stock.analysis_c IN ('FB', 'FP', 'RM', '[PK]')
stock.warehouse = 'FH'
```

For each of these the selectivity of the criteria is essential. For example if 90% of your rows have `pod.status` C, then you should probably add a filtered index for status <> 'C' (and same thing with `poh.status` field too).

For `stock` table `warehouse` (and `analysis_c`): If the given criteria limits the data a lot, adding index to the field should help.

if `pod.qty_ordered` is usually less or equal to `pod.qty_received`, it might be a good idea to add a computed persistent column and index that and use it in the where clause.

Since these fields are in different tables, the query should start from the one that limits the data most, so you might want to index that table only, the others might not help at all. Also I assume you have already indexes for the fields you're joining the tables with. If not, that's the first thing to look at. Always when adding new indexes, it of course has a (small) impact on inserts / updates.

If the query does a lot of key lookups, it might be help if you add all the other columns from that table as included columns into the index, but that also has a impact on updates / inserts.